# Why is a function that is defined in one translation unit accessible in a different translation unit where it is forward declared as static?

Tags: c++

I have two translation units in my application.

In the first translation unit, there is a function `getX()` which has external linkage by default.
In the second translation unit, which has the main function, `getX()` is forward declared as static and is invoked.

However, the code compiles and runs fine and only a warning is thrown. In my understanding, this should have thrown an error while trying to invoke `getX()` in main.

```
// Anon.cpp
#include<iostream>
int getX() {
    return 1;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
static int getX();
int main() {    
    cout << getX() << endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5425ac40f09cb345).  There is no way the second example would link successfully.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Your link only has one of the two translation units, so isn't a good reproduction attempt.

Comment: *Your link only has one of the two translation units* -- That is exactly the point I'm making.  Unless the OP is running something different, there is no way for that second code to link successfully.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think you misunderstood the question. OP is linking both translation units together, while you seem to be assuming that each one is linked separately.

Comment: *OP is linking both translation units together,* -- That's what the OP thinks they are doing.  We don't know, since we don't have the command-line.  In Visual Studio, it certainly does not build, even if you have two separate compilation units.

Comment: [Cannot replicate](https://onlinegdb.com/rJAWghkjP).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ allows to have project with several files easily. (I think you can do (hack) it with coliru by referencing shared link, or creating new file in command line :/)

Comment: OK thanks.  I am used to using only one source unit for those online compilers.

Comment: What compiler are you using?